# How a servlet request data from other servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Ok i was using only response.sendRedirect and forward to work with bought servlets but now i need that a servlet request the answer and not send the client to the other servlet.

How can i do this ?

let me give a example: Imagine a servlet that gives you the time and the temperature in one page.

int this servlet u ll need to request data from 2 diferent servlets so you will need what im asking here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the both servlets runs in the same context on the same server, then just use [`RequestDispatcher#include()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29).

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/otherservleturl").include(request, response);
```

---

You can even do it in a JSP which is been forwarded by the first servlet.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

with

```
<jsp:include page="/otherservleturl" />
```

---

If they don't run in the same context, then you need to programmatically fire a HTTP request on it and pipe its HTTP response output to the current response output.

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://other.com/servlet").openStream();
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(input, output);
```

For more advanced HTTP requests, check [this mini-tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests).

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the fact that you're making a request *from* a servlet - it's just normal Java code.

Ignore the fact that you're making a request *to* a servlet - it's just a normal HTTP request.

Use whatever you normally use for dealing with HTTP - e.g. [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), or the built-in `URLConnection` class. Fetch the data, combine it with any other data, serve it as the response.